# Can Travis CI be configured to deploy to a private NPM on Nodejitsu?

Tags: npm, travis-ci, nodejitsu

I would like to use [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) to build, test and deploy my project as a NPM module to our private registry hosted by [Nodejitsu](https://www.nodejitsu.com/npm/).

I've followed the [instructions Travis CI provides](http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/npm/) for publishing to npmjs.org, which involve adding the following to your `.travis.yml`:

```
deploy:
  provider: npm
  email: ...
  api_key: ...
```

This configuration works perfectly to deploy to npmjs.org. Nodejitsu has [some documentation](http://blog.nodejitsu.com/deploying-to-nodejitsu-from-travis-ci/) on deploying full node.js applications using Travis CI that mentions switching the provider to `nodejitsu` instead of `npm`. This fails with `missing user` and `failed to deploy` errors with no additional details. The user in question is an owner of the module and can publish successfully from the command line.

Does anyone know if Travis CI is supposed to be able to deploy to a private NPM, specifically one hosted by Nodejitsu? Thanks!